# Cades Digital sign with smartcard

Tags: python, windows, digital-signature, smartcard, pkcs#7

I'm try to develop a software for Digital signing xml files and output a .p7m file format. The problem is that I have to use a smartcard to do that. Could you please, show me some resources to learn how to achieve that?

Comment: It might take some time to read this, but it will help you a lot in the long run. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check if this link is of any help http://help.signer.digital/digital_signing_and_authentication_from_web_browser.htm